# Sniffing an Android app to find API URL

Tags: android, wireshark, packet-capture, packet-sniffers, network-security

I'm curious as to how I could figure out the API URL an Android application (any app I have installed) uses if it makes API calls to some online server (a RESTful service for example). I presume I have to capture packets on the device and maybe analyse them in Wireshark or something to find the URL? I'm fairly competent in Java/Android development, but a bit lost when it comes to any sort of network analysis business.

Comment: You could use a debugging HTTP proxy like Charles.

Comment: Essentially, you install Charles on your computer, tell your Android device to use that computer as a HTTP proxy, and then all requests will be sent through there, allowing you to see the individual requests made through apps. SSL is a little more complicated.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

you can do this with help of [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/). I am listing steps here

1. Install **WireShark** on your computer
2. now we have to create Android virtual device(AVD) so we will download Android SDK from official site. Android SDK come with emulator for testing
3. after setting up Android SDK, create a Android virtual Device(AVD) on which we will install app
4. start that virtual device. you can use command line to start (`emulator @<AVD name>`)
5. after creating virtual device install app using adb command `adb install app_file_name.apk`
6. now we can start capturing the packets so I will suggest to close other application on your computer which are using network so our captured packets would be more relevant.
7. now start wireshark with root access
8. select interface which you want to capture and click start to start capturing.

   [image: wireshar start image]
9. now start using that app so packets will transfer to and fro and wireshark will capture it.

   [image: list of packets]
10. if you have used app covering all sort of activity then you can stop wireshark to capture packets.
11. now start main business to analyse packets carefully but not all packets are usefull for our job. so lets filter packets which are relevant for you. lets your IP address is 192.168.0.32 then filter all the packets whose IP is this. so filter expression will be `ip.addr==192.168.0.32`  apply this filter. still we an apply another filter to list up only relevant packets only so possibly that app is accessing API with HTTP protocol so apply HTTP filter. expression would be `http`. you can apply both are filter at once `ip.addr==192.168.0.32 and http` press enter to apply.

    [image: wireshark details]
12. see the info carefully for listed packets you will see lot of important details, API keys, cookies etc

Comment: you have to install android sdk to get adb and emulator

Comment: what about https? İf app connecting over https protocol still can whireshark log?

Comment: with https, protocol is "TLS 1.2" and the request is encrypted so, the request is logged by wireshark BUT not much usefull info (No endpoint, no cookies)

Comment: does it show https log?

Comment: It should be noted that interfering in any packets can actually be in breach of law in some countries

Answer (score 31):

A very fast method.
Go to PlayStore, search for [**Packet Capture**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture)

Download, install and run. 
It's easy simple and fast. It will give you details about the APIs, URLs and response with their headers.

*This application follows the concept of [Packet Sniffing](https://www.lifewire.com/introduction-to-packet-sniffing-2486803). Thus, this might not work with much secured applications like WhatsApp, Facebook, Twitter.*

**UPDATE 1:** 
The  <strike>[**Packet Capture**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture)</strike> is no more available in playstore, try [**OS Monitor**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor)

**UPDATE 2:** 
The  [**Packet Capture**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture) is available again.

Comment: The app is no more available on Play Store. Is there any replacement solution?

Comment: @118218 You can try with this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor

Comment: The original suggested app is still available (again) as before.

Comment: This is easy and worked for me. This should be the accepted answer, Thanks.

Comment: Currently broken in recent android.

Comment: Any alternative? Because this app is not available for my device even if my phone has newer version for android.

Comment: @AliSajjad I haven't had a chance to really test it out, but check out my comment I left [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778072/sniffing-an-android-app-to-find-api-url#comment137109519_58681628)

Answer (score 5):

In windows 10 machine just follow the below steps:

1. Go to Settings > Network & Internet > Mobile hotspot and enable Share my internet connection with other devices.
2. Connect your Mobile Device to that shared hotspot.
3. Now for getting internet access in your mobile click on Change adapter options.
4. Go to properties by right click on the the Network Adapter from which the internet is
   being shared to your windows machine.
5. Tick the Internet Connection Sharing  options in the Sharing tab by selecting the
   appropriate connection (Local Area Connection used by mobile device) and click ok.

Now you will be able to see all the network traffic of the mobile device in Wireshark if you select the Local Area Connection used by mobile. For filtering the result by http traffic you can enter http in the filter field and for `https` web traffic you can enter `tls.handshake.type eq 1`

Comment: easy solution, but for analyzing HTTPS content with modern Android Apps it's nearly impossible

Answer (score 4):

Download Android +6.0 image for PC from this site: https://www.android-x86.org/.

For example: https://www.android-x86.org/releases/releasenote-6-0-r3.html

Make sure that your app works with this Android version -- you can check the minimum Android version on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps) store --, and don't take a too high number for the Android version: the higher the number, the more security constraints is has.

Install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), mount the ISO image, boot Android, and install the app through Google Play.

Now you have a few options:

1. If traffic is unencrypted, you can log all NIC traffic to a text file. e.g. `VBoxManage modifyvm "vm-name" --nictrace1 on --nictracefile1 c:\file.pcap` (cf. [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Network_tips)), or just follow the [steps outlined in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778072/sniffing-an-android-app-to-find-api-url#23568041) with Wireshark.
2. If traffic is encrypted, you can't use (1) but you can use a man-in-the-middle approach. An app that allows this is [HttpCanary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.guoshi.httpcanary&hl=nl) (renamed to [Requable](https://github.com/reqable/reqable-app)?). It will make a VPN connection and redirect your traffic through that VPN. It decrypts and works well, but take care with your private data.
3. If the app is using certificate pinning, then it becomes more complicated. Read this [blog](https://secvibe.com/android-appsec-27855dca8531#.p4svueehn). You will have to use [this](https://gist.github.com/goncalor/586a6a8da585b118b18a86a69635fd06) approach on x86 images. Note that in that article, the author is using Android x86 8.1 (not x64!) and Xposed Android SDK27. Good luck!!

Comment: HTTPCanary was the only solution that just worked for me

Comment: Honestly think this should be the accepted answer! HttpCanary is what I used in the past and I forgot the name since it was removed from the app store. Got the APK and able to introspect my APIs just fine :)

Comment: Looks like it has been renamed to [Reqable](https://github.com/reqable/reqable-app)

Answer (score 0):

Use debug proxy. Click on the play Button and you will be able to capture URLs and view more details

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dans.apps.webd

Answer (score 0):

1. install  virtual box and  genymotion
   http://www.2daygeek.com/install-upgrade-oracle-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-centos-debian-fedora-mint-rhel-opensuse/
   and http://www.2daygeek.com/install-genymotion-android-emulator-on-ubuntu-centos-debian-fedora-rhel-opensuse-arch-linux-mint/#
2. Run genymotion .
   3 . after that your desire android ADV install .
3. now start wireshark with root access

Answer (score 0):

try classic [tcpdump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump)

```
$ tcpdump -D
1.eth0 [Up, Running, Connected]
2.any (Pseudo-device that captures on all interfaces) [Up, Running]
3.lo [Up, Running, Loopback]
4.bluetooth-monitor (Bluetooth Linux Monitor) [Wireless]
5.usbmon2 (Raw USB traffic, bus number 2)
6.usbmon1 (Raw USB traffic, bus number 1)
7.usbmon0 (Raw USB traffic, all USB buses) [none]
8.nflog (Linux netfilter log (NFLOG) interface) [none]
9.nfqueue (Linux netfilter queue (NFQUEUE) interface) [none]
10.dbus-system (D-Bus system bus) [none]
11.dbus-session (D-Bus session bus) [none]
12.bluetooth0 (Bluetooth adapter number 0)
13.eth1 [none, Disconnected]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this thread is quite old but in 2022 using Postman Proxy can help.
Check this link out to see the simple steps
https://blog.postman.com/using-postman-proxy-to-capture-and-inspect-api-calls-from-ios-or-android-devices/

see here to setup for https traffic https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/capturing-https-traffic/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: https://github.com/kendarorg/HttpAnsweringMachine
Is able to record (change and replay) all http AND https calls plus intercepting all servers contacted. Just set it up like this: https://github.com/kendarorg/HttpAnsweringMachine/blob/main/docs/generated/googlehack_android.md add the dns and ssl certificates for the addresses you need to capture then record them (https://github.com/kendarorg/HttpAnsweringMachine/blob/main/docs/generated/localsample.md). It will store everything readable. Just need a pc or mac with java 11 and is ready to start :) PS I am the creator of the project :p