# Watch api(s) consumed by android application

Tags: android, json, api, hotspot

I am looking for a way to see what API(s) is an android app using (with request headers). I think there is some way to connect it with hotspot of our computer system but i probably forgot the whole procedure. Any help would appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wireshark for that. Here is old question and answer about that. [Sniffing an Android app to find API URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778072/sniffing-an-android-app-to-find-api-url)

Comment: Also "Charles Proxy" is another product for this.